# pandas fillna using dict map and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data as shown below:

```
qty_min qty_max region_min region_max subj region
11            1         10         10   ab     UK
21            1        nan         20   ab     UK
nan         nan        nan         30   ab     UK
nan           2        nan         34   bc     US
nan           2         20        nan   bc     US
10          nan        nan        nan   bc     TZ
11          nan        nan         47   de     TZ
13            3        109         31   de     TZ

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

I would like to `fillna()` in each of the columns: `qty_min`, `qty_max`, `region_min`, `region_max` based on a pattern.

For example: If there is `NaN` in `qty_min` and `qty_max` columns, we need to `fillna()` using `groupby` of `subj` and `ffill().bfill()`.

Similarly, if there is `NaN` in `region_max`, `region_min`, we need to `fillna()` using `groupby` of `region` and `ffill().bfill()`

So, I tried the below:

```
df['qty_min'] = df.groupby(['subj'], sort=False)['qty_min'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
df['qty_max'] = df.groupby(['subj'], sort=False)['qty_max'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
df['region_min'] = df.groupby(['region'], sort=False)['region_min'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
df['region_max'] = df.groupby(['region'], sort=False)['region_max'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

As you can see that this is not elegant. Moreover, I have 20 plus columns like this in real data which I would like to fill using the same way (`groupby` column and `ffill.bfill()`)

I have created a `dict` like below manually to identify the corresponding `groupby` column for filling `NaN`.

I'm open to modifying the way we store this info. You can use whatever data structure is easy.

```
fillna_dict= {
  "subj": ['qty_min','qty_max'],
  "region": ['region_min','region_max']
}
```

Is there any elegant and efficient approach to do this?

I expect my output to be like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have separate conditions you need to have several lines.

What you would do is to refactor the code to reuse the groups and a single function:

```
f = lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()

g1 = df.groupby(['subj'], sort=False)
g2 = df.groupby(['region'], sort=False)

df['qty_min'] = g1['qty_min'].apply(f)
df['qty_max'] = g1['qty_max'].apply(f)
df['region_min'] = g2['region_min'].apply(f)
df['region_max'] = g2['region_max'].apply(f)
```

Using your dictionary:

```
f = lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()

fillna_dict= {
  "subj": ['qty_min','qty_max'],
  "region": ['region_min','region_max']
}

for k, cols in fillna_dict.items():
    df[cols] = df.groupby(df[k])[cols].apply(f)
```

output:

```
   qty_min  qty_max  region_min  region_max subj region
0     11.0      1.0        10.0        10.0   ab     UK
1     21.0      1.0        10.0        20.0   ab     UK
2     21.0      1.0        10.0        30.0   ab     UK
3     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
4     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
5     10.0      2.0       109.0        47.0   bc     TZ
6     11.0      3.0       109.0        47.0   de     TZ
7     13.0      3.0       109.0        31.0   de     TZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in a function:

```py
for k,v in fillna_dict.items():
     df[v] = df.groupby([k], sort=False)[v].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Output:

```
   qty_min  qty_max  region_min  region_max subj region
0     11.0      1.0        10.0        10.0   ab     UK
1     21.0      1.0        10.0        20.0   ab     UK
2     21.0      1.0        10.0        30.0   ab     UK
3     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
4     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
5     10.0      2.0       109.0        47.0   bc     TZ
6     11.0      3.0       109.0        47.0   de     TZ
7     13.0      3.0       109.0        31.0   de     TZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Restructure your dictionary and try:

```
fillna_dict= {"qty_min": "subj",
              "qty_max": "subj",
              "region_min": "region",
              "region_max": "region"
              }

df[list(fillna_dict.keys())] = df[list(fillna_dict.keys())].apply(lambda x: df.groupby(fillna_dict[x.name], sort=False)[x.name].ffill().bfill())

>>> df
   qty_min  qty_max  region_min  region_max subj region
0     11.0      1.0        10.0        10.0   ab     UK
1     21.0      1.0        10.0        20.0   ab     UK
2     21.0      1.0        10.0        30.0   ab     UK
3     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
4     10.0      2.0        20.0        34.0   bc     US
5     10.0      2.0       109.0        47.0   bc     TZ
6     11.0      3.0       109.0        47.0   de     TZ
7     13.0      3.0       109.0        31.0   de     TZ
```